# Change appengine console red color in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

appengine console for local development logs are an eye sore red(like a bunch of errors!!!) by default. How can I change that to standard black for normal log and red for error? If I right click on the console and go to preference, the setting is correct : standard black and error red.

[image]

Comment: Does appengine use logback? I know there is a way to do it with logback under slf4j but can't seem to find the answer right now as I did it 2 years ago. (stumbled on your post looking for the answer).

Answer (score 2):

The output from the DevAppServer is sent to stderr, so you need to change the error colour to black.

Comment: why would they do that? It is not only appengine project that I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

*Note after one year : I do not use 'java.util.logging' anymore. I had have got a strange bug where my thread stopped in the  method 'log()'. It was probably a dead lock. I've swith to 'Log4j'.*

In order to have the errors logged in red and the infos in black in the eclipse console, you can create your own ConsoleHandler:

```
public class MyConsoleHandler extends StreamHandler {           
    private java.util.logging.Formatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
     public void publish(LogRecord record){      
         if(record.getLevel().intValue() < Level.WARNING.intValue())
             System.out.println(formatter.formatMessage(record));            
         else
             System.err.println(formatter.format(record));
     }
}
```

and use plug it with:

```
java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().reset(); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new MyConsoleHandler())
```

Comment: My 1.9.0 GAE SDK tells me that LogManager is not supported, so I guess one could instead do Logger.getHandlers to get current handlers, and then Logger.removeHandlers to remove them, and THEN call addHandler.